# Estimation of a summatory by an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality

This may be inmediate, but I'm not able to see it right now. Why this inequality holds, for $n\geq 2$?

$$
\sum_{k\geq 2} e^{-k}k^{n-1} \leq \Gamma(n) := \int_0^{\infty}e^{-x} x^{n-1} dx
$$

Comment: Perhaps the Euler-Maclaurin formula (which relates sums to integrals) would provide some information here.

Comment: @NoName how did $f(0)$ disappear in second implication? Nvm, I see that $f(0)=0$. I was confused if you were plugging in zero for $x$ or $n$.

Comment: That's right. There's also a typo ($x$ in the sum that shouldn't be there), but I can no longer edit the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\displaystyle \int_N^ \infty f(x) \, \mathrm dx $ is finite we have the following [estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence#Remark):

$$\displaystyle \int_N^\infty f(x)\, \mathrm dx\le\sum_{n=N}^\infty f(n)\le f(N)+\int_N^\infty f(x)\, \mathrm dx $$

Looking at the upper bound for the series we have:

$$\begin{aligned} & ~~~~~~~~~~~\sum_{n=N}^\infty f(n)\le f(N)+\int_N^\infty f(x)\, \mathrm dx  \\& \implies  \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-k}k^{n-1}\le f(0)+\int_0^\infty e^{-x}x^{n-1}\, \mathrm dx  \\& \implies   \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-k}k^{n-1} \le  \int_0^\infty e^{-x}x^{n-1}\, \mathrm dx \\& \implies \displaystyle \frac{1}{e}+  \sum_{k \ge 2} e^{-k}k^{n-1} \le  \int_0^\infty e^{-x}x^{n-1}\, \mathrm dx \\& \implies  \displaystyle  \sum_{k \ge 2} e^{-k}k^{n-1} \le  \int_0^\infty e^{-x}x^{n-1}\, \mathrm dx \end{aligned} $$

Answer (score 2):

You can sketch the function, and draw the summation as a set of rectangles of width $1$ each, and compare that with the area under the curve.  Be careful to avoid fencepost ("off by one") errors.  Check if you are using right hand sums or left hand sums and whether they are over or under estimates.  Your sum starts with $k=2$.  Where should you place that rectangle?

You already have an analytic proof in the comments but I find geometric proofs easier to understand intuitively.